# How to alias an awk command

Tags: linux

I want to alias the below into a more easy term say aprint.

```
 awk '{print $1}'
```

I did

```
alias aprint "awk \'{print $1}\'"   //But gave error ----> Missing }.
```

then I gave,

```
alias aprint "awk \'\{print $1\}\'"  
//But gave error ----> awk: '{print , awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

I'm not sure how to work around this, please help...

Comment: Did you tried

alias aprint='awk \'{print $1}\''           ???

Answer (score 17):

There are a couple of problems with your alias.

First, the name of an alias is separated from its value by `=`, not white space.

Second, a `'` cannot be nested within other quotes by escaping them with a `\`.

Your alias will work if written like this:

```
alias aprint='awk "{print \$1}"'
```

where the `$` is preceded by a `\` to prevent `$1` from being expanded by the shell.

Answer (score 7):

Better than an `alias`, create a function for this kind of thing:

```
function aprint() { awk '{print $1}'; }
```

You can use it for example like this:

```
$ date
Fri Jan  3 08:09:23 CET 2014
$ date | aprint
Fri
```

You probably want to parameterize it too:

```
function aprint() { awk "{print \$${1:-1}}"; }
```

This way it will work with not only the 1st but any column easily:

```
$ date | aprint 2
Jan
$ date | aprint 6
2014
```

Using `${1:-1}` the argument is optional, and by default it will use 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
alias somefunc='function _somefunc { ls -la ${1} |awk '\''{print $1}''\'; }; _somefunc'
```

Alias is fun like this.  Not sure why you would setup an alias for awk per se, but if you do put it in a function and tokenize the input.

I usually use this when I want to tokenize some output and pass it on to something else, which is far more useful in aliases.  This can work with a regular alias too, just be sure to use ; to demarcate the end of the alias before the single tick:
e.g. `alias other='ls -la |awk '\''{print $1}'\'';'`